# Showing specific kernel density contours using QGIS Animove?

Tags: qgis, kernel-density

This is more a graphics question (I calculated all the important stuff in R), but is it possible to edit the **Kernel Density Estimation** (KDE) output layers given by the **Animove** plugin to show only the 50% and 95% contours?

Currently it gives me somthing like a heatmap that I cannot change.

[image: "heatmap" KDE - I only want the 95% and 50% contours]

---

@csk -  see attachment. Also I just realised that the created layer isn't saved with the project, so it seems like Animove calculates/creates temporary data-layers...?

[image]

Comment: Are the contours all in one layer? What does the attribute table of that layer look like?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.